# upload geojson file to Mapbox API

Tags: python, python-requests, mapbox-gl-js

I have Geopandas dataFrame, I am converting this into Geojson string and uploading it into MAPbox API.

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="GEOMETRY")
geojson_str = gdf.to_json()
url = f"https://api.mapbox.com/uploads/v1/{username}/credentials?access_token={my_access_token}"
payload = {
    "name": "mydata",
    "file": geojson_str,
    "format": "geojson",
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
job_id = response.json()["job"]
status_url = f"https://api.mapbox.com/uploads/v1/{username}/{job_id}/status?access_token={my_access_token}"
status_response = requests.get(status_url)
```

I am getting s3-bucket,accesskey,secretaccess  since MAPBOX API uses S3 Bucket for staging. I am not receiving job from the response. Is there any way to upload geojson to MapBOX API.

Comment: What does your response say? `response.status_code` or `response.text`?

Comment: response.code is 401

Comment: That means you don't have the right credentials to access the resource. Are you sure you set up your `api` credentials correctly?

Comment: yeah but I am able to list out all the datasets inside Mapbox APi with same credentials.

Comment: It could be that you have restricted access with the `api` key that you currently have.